# HTML5: How to Move/Change a Video's Position with a Button

Tags: javascript, html, video, position, move

I am fairly new to HTML5 and Javascript. I have only created simple websites so I apologize in advance for my limited knowledge. A friend needs some help and I offered to take a crack at it.

The concept is simple enough:
-Have a button that will adjust the position of a video up or down.

-The video should be contained inside a window. The window will hold a smaller resolution compared to the video, in order to hide the rest of the video and only reveal the portion within the window.

Reference images to help illustrate the idea are below (I can only post 2):
[Ref-Button1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EB8WQ.jpg)
[Ref-Button2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsuTF.jpg)

Is this possible?

Through researching, I am under the impression that a moveable div or possibly a canvas might be the right approach.

So far, all of my attempts are failing. I don't think it will help much, but an example of my script is also provided if needed.

Any insight is greatly appreciated.

```
<style>
    body {
    background-color: Grey
    color: #CCCCCC;
    }

    #videoWindow {
    width: 720px;
    height: 350px;
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    border: 7px solid #0F0F0F;
    border-radius: 5px;
    }

    #videoControls {
    margin-left: 400px;
    margin-right: 400px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    width: 400px;
    height: 250px;
    }

    #videoManip {
    width: 720px;
    height: 350px;
        }

</style>


<body>
<div>  
   <!--Video Window (Static)-->
   <div id="videoWindow" class="videoWindow">

   <!--Video Re-Positioner-->
   <div id="videoManip" class="videoManip">
      <!--Video--> 
      <video id="video" width="720" height="1050">
      <source src="Videos/VideoPlayerTest.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</div>

      <!--VideoPositionControls-->
      <div class=""><!--SetClass-->

      <!--Button1-->
      <input type="button" id="button1" value="Button1">

      <!--Button2-->
      <input type="button" id="button2" value="Button2">

      <!--Button3-->
      <input type="button" id="button3" value="Button3">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>


<script>

   //Video
   var video = document.getElementById("video");

   //VideoPositionControls
   var Btn1 = document.getElementById("button1");
   var Btn2 = document.getElementById("button2");
   var Btn3 = document.getElementById("button3");

   //Event Listener: Video Position Controls
   //Update Video Position for 'Cam1'
   Btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
   video.DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC(0,0)

   //Update Video Position for 'Cam2'
   Btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
   video.DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC(0,350)

   //Update Video Position for 'Cam3'
   Btn3.addEventListener("click", function() {
   video.DOCUMENT_POSITION_IMPLEMENTATION_SPECIFIC(0,-350)

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The most easy way to do that is to just move video vertically inside its parent.

Addition to **CSS:**

```
#videoManip {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#video {
  position: relative;
}
```

Addition to **javascript**:

```
Btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
  video.style.top = 0;
});
Btn2.addEventListener("click", function() {
  video.style.top = '-350px';
});
Btn3.addEventListener("click", function() {
  video.style.top = '-700px';
});
```

Here is tiny jsfiddle illustrating that: https://jsfiddle.net/iStyx/ocgx6pdL/

Comment: Sorry, new to this site, getting used to the responding. I've given your recommendation a shot and am having trouble getting it working properly.  There is a reaction happening so that's a good sign, but the video simply reacts with a short flicker and then continues playing. It seems like it is trying to re-position but won't stick to that position.  Any ideas? (I will provide my scripting below)

Answer (score 0):

You could use [JQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) to achieve that.

First define two buttons with an onclick event.

```
<div id="videoControls">
    <button id="move-up" onclick="move(0,1)">Up</button>
    <button id="move-down" onclick="move(0,-1)">Down</button>
</div>
```

The following code handles the actual positioning with jquery. The function move takes 2 parameters x and y for the number of pixels the video should move along the axis. In this example it uses margin for positioning. You should check if it's good with your use-case.

```
const STEP = 10;
const VIDEO_ID="video";
function move(x,y){
    var valx = "+="+(STEP*x)+"px";
    var valy = "+="+(STEP*y)+"px";
    $(VIDEO_ID).css( 'margin-top', valy );
    $(VIDEO_ID).css( 'margin-left', valx );
}
```